# Fineuploader delete file from S3 not work but no error

Tags: fine-uploader

So I have been using S3 uploads for a while and today I thought I would also try the delete file option, so I inserted
  deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                endpoint: '/s3handler'
            }
When testing after an upload , indeed the "delete" button appears and I click it and it does it's deleting message and then goes away. 
The thing is that the file/s are not deleted from the S3 bucket.

I have checked that the user has been granted delete permission and i also noted that CORS on the bucket also allows for delete
I would have thought if it did not work there would be some error, but no error is shown

Answer (score 0):

Fine Uploader sends the delete request to your server, and then your server is expected to make the call to S3 to actually delete the file. Your server must be acknowledging the delete request with a 200 response code, in which case the file is deleted as far as Fine Uploader is concerned.

Comment: Ok, it does seem like this is true, since there would otherwise be an error... but not deleting from S3 for sure

Comment: perhaps because i alter the file name when uploading? I insert the var filename = $("#uploader2").fineUploader("getName", fileId);
                                      return "home/"+userid+"/uploads/"+userid+'_'+filename;

Comment: I don't understand what the endpoint is supposed to be,. deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        forceConfirm: true,
        endpoint: 'server/file'
    }
}); In an S3 environment what is "server/file" --- also sorry about formatting, I dont know how to make a line break in here

Comment: This should be the endpoint of your server that will handle delete file requests.

Comment: i had it correct, then got moved away from the docs which are not for s3. So I have the endpoint as the php handler file which i right. Still it wont delete the file. I need to compare my php file with yours at http://s3-demo.fineuploader.com/s3demo-thumbnails-cors.php how can i get a copy please

Comment: All PHP S3 examples used on the home page can be found at https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/tree/master/php/s3.

Comment: my file looks ok then, same delete function options. What can I do, it's a mystery, how can i show you my php file ( i not sure how to use github)